# Is there any notation for two vector subspaces being orthogonal complements?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be an inner product space with subspaces $U, W$. These subspaces being orthogonal complements means that
$$\begin{align*}
&1) \ \ U \perp W\\
& 2) \ \ \ U + W = V
\end{align*}$$

Is there any popular notation for expressing this more compactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fond of $U\oplus^{\perp}W=V$.

Comment: Nice, even if it's unfamiliar to someone, it will get the point across.

Comment: Have you seen it anywhere else, or is it something you made up?

Comment: It's what I learned in my linear algebra lectures.